# Can we replace all "int" parameter & return types with "IntPtr" in the DllImport method signature?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dllimport, intptr

In my program, I have some `DllImport`s since I want to call some native APIs. `int` type is used for the method parameters & returns types. It was working quite well until I ran my application on new Windows 2012 R2 Server (64 bit). The problem is fixed when I changed one of the `ref` parameter's type from `int` to `IntPtr`.

I know that `IntPtr` is used to represent a pointer or a handle.
However, MSDN also says that `IntPtr` is "designed to be an integer" whose size is platform-specific. So if `IntPtr` is capable of handling the platform specific size of the integer, is it OK to replace all `int` parameters & return types with `IntPtr`?

I am using C# .NET 4.0.

Comment: It'd probably work, but the proper way is to look up the signature of the method on msdn and then check the type overview tqble to see ehich ones have native size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot blindly do this.  64-bit code still heavily uses 32-bit integral types, their "native integer" is still a 32-bit value.  If you see an *int* or a *long* in the native code declaration (or an equivalent typedef alias) then you still use *int* in your pinvoke declaration.

While that might not sound like a very sensible thing to do for a 64-bit compiler, there is a very good reason why they did not upgrade their native integer type.  Modern processors are extraordinary fast but are limited by how fast they can address memory.  Their execution engines run at gigahertz speeds but the memory bus is glacially slow.  An electrical design problem related to distance, the further a signal has to travel the slower it needs to change state to still be recognized correctly at the other end of the wire.  A problem solved partially by using *caches*, copies of memory that are located close to the execution engine.  Those caches don't double in size.  Using the caches effectively is *very* important to speed, so using 32-bit integral values where possible is important.

Examples of native types that *are* IntPtr are any pointer type, size_t, XXX_PTR, WPARAM, LRESULT.  The latter are typedefs, they can make it difficult to recognize the underlying type.  When in doubt, write a little C program that uses `sizeof` so you know a fact.

The formal definition is the [data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) used by the 64-bit native compiler.  Microsoft compilers use LLP64.

Answer (score 1):

> is it OK to replace all int parameters & return types with IntPtr

No it isn't. You'd need to look at each use case individually. Where a pointer is required (for example to receive output) then `IntPtr` is more likely to be correct because it'll be sized correctly for the platform's pointer width as you've found out.

A C# `int` [is 32-bits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx) regardless of whether the the underlying OS is 32 or 64 bits and will match corresponding fixed width parameter types in the Win32 API. `LONG` is one example with `DWORD` as its unsigned equivalent. There [are others](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), many others...